# Retrofit. Parse only nested object

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I need to parse only one list of objects from JSON object with Retroft.
Here's my JSON file
[image]

I need only "similar" array from it. Also I've already created POJO for elements of this array

[image]

Is there a way to make this without making POJO for the rest of the JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make pojo with necessary fields:

```
data class ServerResponse(
    val recipe: RecipeResponse
)

data class RecipeResponse(
    val similar: List<RecipeBrief>
)
```